# proper static final use without causing a memory leak

Tags: java

I have a SearchUtil class where I have a bunch of static final methods. My app appears to have a memory leak some wheres and I've been having a very difficult time tracking it down. I'm wondering if my use of static final might be the cause. Here's an example code snippet.

```
public static final List<String> getYearRange(SearchFilter searchFilter) {
    List<String> yearRange = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Integer toYear = searchFilter.getToYear() != null ? Integer.parseInt(searchFilter.getToYear()) : null;
        Integer fromYear = searchFilter.getFromYear() != null ? Integer.parseInt(searchFilter.getFromYear()) : null;

        if (toYear != null && fromYear != null) {
            while (fromYear <= toYear) {
                yearRange.add(String.valueOf(fromYear++));
            }
        } else if (toYear != null) {
            yearRange.add(String.valueOf(toYear));
        } else if (fromYear != null) {
            yearRange.add(String.valueOf(fromYear));
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    return yearRange;
}
```

Comment: No, a `static final` **method** cannot in itself be the cause of your memory leak. No method can be the cause of your memory leak.

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak?

Comment: There's no point ever declaring a method `static final`.

Comment: Memory leaks cannot occur in java. You can only keep a reference on a object that prevent it from being collected.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Actually, there is. It's to avoid [hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) the static method in a subclass.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Why not? `final` ensures the `static` method cannot be hidden by a subclass.

Comment: I'm with @notanormie on this one.  Are you *sure* you have a memory leak?  A lot of people see things like Tomcat not bothering to GC until it's almost full and think that their application is leaking memory somehow.

Comment: I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError and in the stack this is one of the methods. I tried increasing the heap from 1024 all the way up to 4 gigs with the same issue. This is the first time I've ever experienced this kind of behavior, so I'm struggling to track down the core issue.

Comment: Well, this method is just creating and returning a `List`.  It is allocating memory, which explains why it'll show up in the stack of the `OutOfMemoryError`, but it's not holding on to anything in memory which could grow.  I would suggest taking a look at whatever is invoking this method, and think about what it's doing with the data.

Comment: Than this probably isn't a memory leak, just you holding references to a whole lot of objects. Memory leak would be incorrect handling of memory so it wouldn't be released when not using it anymore. Java seems to think you need all that memory allocated. Other code than this should be inspected. This only allocates some memory but doesn't hold references.

Comment: @CodeJunkie if you're getting an `OutOfMemoryException` i personally would take a look at the `while` loop. Maybe the condition is somehow always true, or at least long enough to fill up your memory.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm rather surprised to see this happening to begin with. I'm generally very good at writing stateless code, but perhaps I missed something. Any good recommendations for a profiler? I used the built in one within netbeans, but it appears to crash under advanced profiling.

Comment: @MaxMega there is range restrictions in the code that produces the years that would prevent that from happening.

Comment: @CodeJunkie There seems to be nothing to ensure to/fromYear are *sane* values. If you have a miscalculation somewhere toYear may be very large or fromYear negative. That could easily fill the list to a point where you run out of memory. Its one of the first things I'd check.